# ruby - make a script continue to next statement in begin after the exception and done with rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

Consider my code as

```
begin
  aa = 20
  bb = 0
  puts 'before exception'
  c = aa / bb
  puts 'after exception'
rescue
  puts 'in rescue'
end
```

It gives the output as

```
before exception
in rescue
```

If i want to print the 'after exception' as well. How i need to do that?

I need to continue with the next statement after the exception raise. Kindly help me on this.

Edit: I just mentioned a sample code above. Consider, i may not aware where and what exception will occur and it may come any where in the script and after done with executing rescue i need to go back to the next line in begin and work on it. Is there any way to handle this in ruby?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate in the loop and want to continue the loop if it fails for one condition ?

Comment: No @HEraju. If it is a loop i can use 'next', but it is not. consider the exception raising line is not having any dependency with next line. Then i can continue with the next lines.

Comment: Exceptions are non-resumable in Ruby (and most other languages).

Comment: you can split your original method into multiple smaller methods and `rescue` inside them instead of the original one. This way, they will skip the next code statements in smaller method but will run the statements in original method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inside the begin block. Although if any code needs to run even after exception, use `ensure` block for it.

```
begin
  aa = 20
  bb = 0
  puts 'before exception'
  c = aa / bb
rescue
  puts 'in rescue'
ensure
  puts 'after exception'
end
```

Comment: Yea agree. But, if i'm not sure where i got the exception and i need to continue the script. It is not possible?

Comment: If two things might fail, you want to recover from them seprately, so you can continue. A single begin/rescue/ensure won't do the trick. But in this case, two will.

Answer (score 0):

Below is way to solve one such case on custom exception, or you will need to divide the code block into pieces and have a begin end block for what you feel it could look like raise a exception.

```
    class Exception
      attr_accessor :continuation
      def ignore
        continuation.call
      end
    end

    require 'continuation' # Ruby 1.9
    module RaiseWithIgnore
      def raise(*args)
        callcc do |continuation|
          begin
            super
          rescue Exception => e
            e.continuation = continuation
            super(e)
          end
        end
      end
    end

    class Object
      include RaiseWithIgnore
    end

    def mj
      puts 'before exception'
      raise 'll'
      puts 'after exception'
    end

    begin
      mj
      rescue => e
        puts 'in rescue'
        e.ignore 
      end
```

Hope this helps.
source : http://avdi.org/talks/rockymtnruby-2011/things-you-didnt-know-about-exceptions.html

Comment: Thanks @HEraju. Is it possible to use something like `def mj
      puts 'before exception'
      22/0
      puts 'after exception'
    end
` I'm getting an error as `:5:in `ignore': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. Is it possible to use it without raise?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question.  Ruby really should have provided a way to ignore the exception and continue to *the next line in the rescue block*.

It seems the only option is to use inline rescue, which is being frowned upon as not a good style.

```
begin
  aa = 20
  bb = 0
  puts 'before exception'
  c = aa / bb rescue nil
  puts 'after exception'
end
```